# GitLab Auto DevOps issue with Java 11

Tags: java, maven, gitlab

I am trying to use Auto DevOps on GitLab to deploy my Java 11 Spring Boot Maven project to Kubernetes. I am getting the following error:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project ABC: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]

The project builds fine locally. Does anyone know how to fix this on GitLab?

Comment: No, I did not ask the same question as before. The previous question was about deploying from GitLab -> Heroku, where the maven compiler issue happened on Heroku's side. This one is about auto-deploying from GitLab -> Kubernetes. In this case, I have no control over any variables in the GitLab setup.

Comment: Did you verify that Java11 is available on gitlab runner where is it executing maven builds...?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that - the entire process is run automatically. I would assume that is the issue, since it fails to find java version 11.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this changelog post on Hiroku's devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1489), you have to create a file 'system.properties' on your project, with this configuration in it:

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

During the next deployment, the build phase will use OpenJDK 11.

Comment: You may add that maven version can be specified with the same system.properties files, and in july 2021 is limited to 3.6.2:

`maven.version=3.6.2`

Answer (score 0):

Share your pipeline and error logs so that we can get to know what you are facing the issue.

Even you can use the below pipeline to build your project, as per bit information shared by you that indicate you are facing issue while building your project with Gitlab:

Use below pipeline to build:

```
Java_Build:
  stage: build
  image: 
    name: docker:20.10
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - apk update
    - apk add openjdk8
    - apk add maven
  script:
    - mvn clean install
```